# How to modify kivy widget property by id on .py file

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I have a label and a text input, and I wanna change it's text property by a variable on .py file. 
Here's the code:

#### Here's the .kv

```
<DefinicaoDeSaidas>:

    BoxLayout:

        orientation:'vertical'

        BoxLayout:

            orientation:'vertical'

            padding: 0,20,20,50

            Image:

                source:'exemplo.png'

            Label:

                text:'Escolha as missoes para a saida'
                font_size:40

            TextInput:

                id: ti
```

#### Here's the .py

```
class DefinicaoDeSaidas(Screen): 

    #get the values and everything

    #transformate a variable ('name') onto the ti.text property
```

You can see all the code by the github repository: https://github.com/Enzodtz/FLL-Artificial-Inteligence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use id in the .py since it often leads to having a code like `foo_object.ids.ti`, instead you can expose it as a property:

```
<DefinicaoDeSaidas>:
    ti: ti # <---
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            padding: 0,20,20,50

            Image:
                source:'exemplo.png'

            Label:
                text:'Escolha as missoes para a saida'
                font_size:40

            TextInput:
                id: ti
```

And then you can access using self from any method:

```
class DefinicaoDeSaidas(Screen): 
    # ...
    def foo_function(self, another_arguments):
        v = self.ti.text # get text
        self.ti.text = u # update text
```